# Why Does Text Blur on 3D Rotation in React?

Tags: reactjs, rotation, carousel, blur, preserve-3d

I'm creating an image carousel for React that I style and rotate using the code found here: https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel

When I first load the carousel things are nice and clear, but as soon as I rotate it, everything blurs (even once motion has stopped), except the item in the original 0-degree position when it finally rotates back around to the front. I tried using `-webkit-filter: blur(0);` but that doesn't have an impact. Any idea how I can avoid the text blurring?

Before: [image]

After: [image]

I've isolated it to this transform call:

```
transform: rotateY( ${(props : any) => props.yAngle}deg ) translateZ(${(props : any) => props.zAmount}px)
```

Since if I put 0 for the props.yAngle everything is clear but if there's any degree that's not zero there, it all becomes blurred.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm using a Rotate component that accepts the IMG URL and the current rotation angle. Rotating the image using `transform:rotate(${rotation}deg)` results in the image being too blurry to make out...

Comment: No, I haven't. I ended up overlaying the front card with a static "clear" card that I only show when the carousel stops moving. It's not perfect (there is a small dimensional difference between the two if you look closely), but it's better than the blur.